# Angular Ivy Compiler, ngtsc, ngcc, ngc, aot, jit, tsc

Tags: angular9, ivy, aot

I am learning about Angular Ivy Compiler. This is my understanding.

Ivy's compiler - consists of ngtsc and ngcc

ngc - AOT compiler

ngtsc - is a wrapper around tsc

ngcc - is compatbility compiler to compile pre-Ivy libs

tsc - is a typescript compiler

Referred this link, to understand architecture of Ivy  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/design/architecture.md

This link for AOT compiler,
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5b31a0a2942c50059cac4c7ccb92047a50473347/aio/content/guide/aot-compiler.md

Does the AOT compiler and ngtsc(as part of Ivy) both performs this - "converts your Angular HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code" ?

When Ivy + AOT compilation, what are the functionalities of ngtsc and AOT compiler(ngc)?

Thanks